# How to get date with time but including miliseconds?

Tags: angular

I have the following timestamp `1611595957054` and i need to show the date in the following format: `25-01-2021 18:32`:

so i use the angular pipe

```
{{obj.timestamp | amDateFormat:'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm'}}
```

but at the end of the time i need to include also miliseconds so for example

`25-01-2021 18:32.123`

how can i do this ?

Comment: amDateFormat is presumably https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment#amdateformat-pipe? Assuming it uses the same format options as the regular DatePipe, did you read https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options? Or for moment, https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/? Also that seems like a weird requirement, why show the milliseconds but not the seconds?

Comment: You want to ask my client regarding the requirement ? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this: `{{obj.timestamp | amDateFormat:'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS'}}`

You can check out all the date formats [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: Thank you it works.Where did you find info about this possible solution ?

Comment: I got it from this [link](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe). They clearly outline how to format a date from Days, Hours , Time Zone and Milliseconds. For instance, they clearly outline under the **Custom format options** section that `SSS` is _Numeric: 3 digits + zero padded (= milliseconds)_ . The format of the date is the same in most programming languages.